Is covariance estimation via the inverse hessian method generalizable (or possible) for loss functions other than least squares?
I know from other resources such as here that the scaled inverse hessian of your least squares loss can be used to estimate your model's parameter uncertainty (specifcally, covariance), but I can't immediately conceptualize how this process could be generalized to any loss function. I strongly suspect I have simply not found the derivation of this method, or my math background isn't strong enough to see the full picture without help.
From intuition, I can see that this method will only work for loss functions that are continuous and smooth near the local minimum. For example, I would expect that there would exist similar covariance estimates for Huber Loss, Exponential Loss, and Cauchy Loss.
If I have a way of calculating hessians and derivatives numerically, is there a documented formula for this method that is agnostic to the specific implementation of the loss function itself?
